# How to use escape characters in strings

Tags: ruby, string

I've been working my way through the Ruby Koans and am confused by the "escape clauses and single quoted strings" examples.

One example shows that I can't really use escape characters in this way, but immediately after, the following example is given:

```
def test_single_quotes_sometimes_interpret_escape_characters
  string = '\\\''
  assert_equal 2, string.size # <-- my answer is correct according to the program
  assert_equal "\\'", string  # <-- my answer is correct according to the program
end
```

This has confused me on two fronts:

1. Single quotes can sometimes be used with escape characters.
2. Why is the string size `2`, when `assert_equal` is `"\\\'"`? (I personally thought the answer was `"\'"`, which would make more sense with regards to size).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can break your `string` into two pieces to clarify things:

```
string = '\\' + '\''
```

Each part is a string of length one; `'\\'` is the single character `\` and `'\''` is the single character `'`. When you put them together you get the two character string `\'`.

There are two characters that are special within a single quoted string literal: the backslash and the single quote itself. The single quote character is, of course, used to delimit the string so you need something special to get a single quote into a single quoted string, the *something special* is the backslash so `'\''` is a single quoted string literal that represents a string containing one single quote character. Similarly, if you need to get a backslash into a single quoted string literal you escape it with another backslash so `'\\'` has length one and contains one backslash.

The single quote character has no special meaning within a double quoted string literal so you can say `"'"` without any difficulty. The backslash, however, does have a special meaning in double quoted strings so you have to say `"\\"` to get a single backslash into your double quoted string.

Consider your guess off `"\'"`. The single quote has no special meaning within a double quoted string and escaping something that doesn't need escaping just gives you your *something* back; so, if `c` is a character that doesn't need to be escaped within a double quoted string, then `\c` will be just `c`. In particular, `"\'"` evaluates to `"'"` (i.e. one single quote within a double quoted string).

The result is that:

- `'\\\'' == "\\'"`
- `"\\\"" == '\\"'`
- `"\'" == '\''`
- `"\'" == "'"`
- `'\\\''.length == 2`
- `"\\\"".length == 2`
- `"\'".length == 1`
- `"'".length == 1`

The [Wikibooks reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings) that Kassym gave covers these things.

I usually switch to [`%q{}` (similar to single quoting) or `%Q{}` (similar to double quoting)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation) when I need to get quotes into strings, all the backslashes make my eyes bleed.

Comment: That is an excellent explanation; thanks to the both of you for the link. I agree with you also, I think the %q{}/%Q{} option is best for quotes, as it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This might be worth a read : http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :002 > a = '\\\''
 => "\\'" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :003 > a.size
 => 2 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :004 > puts a
\'
```

In single quotes there are only two escape characters : `\\` and `\'`.

Comment: The second assert is correct. There's no need to escape a single quote within double quotes (but you still need to escape the backslash).