# Is is possible to create a string in ruby that keeps escaping characters?

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, user-data

I need to form a user-data script from Ruby so I need all escaping characters to remain. When I do this:

```
  def user_data
     "#!/bin/bash
     sed -i -e '/<Name>loadbalanceServerIP<\/Name>/,/<Value>/s/<Value>[^<]*/<Value>1.1.1.1/' /home/wowza/conf/Server.xml"
  end
```

The string removes the \ in the Name tag. If I put two \, it keeps them both. Any suggestion as how to keep the string the same way I wrote it?

Thank you!

Comment: It's correct ruby behaviour. When you puts your string with double \, you will see only one.

Comment: what's "scaping characters"?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think you should read this as escaping

Comment: If I use two \\ it keeps them both. :(

Comment: @LeticiaEsperon no, it doesn't. It _shows_ two backslashes when you are inspecting the string, but the string contains only one backslash: `"\\".size #=> 1`

Comment: Oh!! That's right. Thank you very much, that was the information I was lacking.

Comment: I'd recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/q/8554479/128421 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character. This is well documented behavior.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem: `"\\".length #=> 1`. Which version of Ruby are you using? Which implementation? How *exactly* are you constructing your `String`? Is it a literal? Does it come from somewhere else? Do you parse it? Generate it? Could there be a double parsing or double escaping bug somewhere in your code?

Comment: This question is different. The OP wants to enter / keep a multi-line string containing `'` and ``\`` (literally) as-is, without having to specifically quote anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`%q` delimiter](http://blog.brzezinka.eu/webmaster-tips/ruby/alternative-stringss-delimiter-for-ruby-on-rails) rather than `"`:

```
def user_data
     %q[#!/bin/bash
     sed -i -e '/<Name>loadbalanceServerIP<\/Name>/,/<Value>/s/<Value>[^<]*/<Value>1.1.1.1/' /home/wowza/conf/Server.xml]
end
```

Comment: If I do that in Rails console it puts <\\/Name>

Comment: `"` is used to define the string. The string starts `"#!/bin/bash ...` and ends on the next line with `....Server.xml"`

Comment: It show that as the property of the string, but if you output it for (example `puts %q[<\/Name>]`) it will be formatted correctly

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. The output of that code is .......<\\/Name>........

Comment: Really? `puts %q[<\/Name>]` outputs `<\/Name>`

Comment: I meant in the rails console without using puts. But you are right. The thing was I dind't know that it was showing two backslashes but they were actually just one!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [heredoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents):

```
def user_data
  <<~'SH'
    #!/bin/bash
    sed -i -e '/<Name>loadbalanceServerIP<\/Name>/,/<Value>/s/<Value>[^<]*/<Value>1.1.1.1/' /home/wowza/conf/Server.xml
  SH
end

puts user_data
```

`~` removes the indentation, and the single quotes around `SH` disable interpolation and escaping.

Output:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sed -i -e '/<Name>loadbalanceServerIP<\/Name>/,/<Value>/s/<Value>[^<]*/<Value>1.1.1.1/' /home/wowza/conf/Server.xml
```